# ArrayList not received from one Fragment to another using bundle and Parcelable

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, bundle, parcelable

I am passing the `ArrayList` from one `Fragment` to another.I am using `Parcelable` to achieve this.I am passing `ArrayList` using `Bundle`.But in another Fragment I am not able to receive this.
This is code for Class which *implements* `Parelable`

```
public class CurrentEntry implements Parcelable{

     String name;
     String people;
     String estimate;



    public CurrentEntry()
    {

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(String people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

    public String getEstimate() {
        return estimate;
    }

    public void setEstimate(String estimate) {
        this.estimate = estimate;
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(this.people);
        dest.writeString(this.estimate);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CurrentEntry> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<CurrentEntry>() {
        public CurrentEntry createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CurrentEntry(in);
        }

        public CurrentEntry[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CurrentEntry[size];
        }
    };

    public CurrentEntry(Parcel in)
    {
        this.name=in.readString();
        this.people=in.readString();
        this.estimate=in.readString();
    }
}
```

This is code for sending ArrayList from one Fragment to Another.

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   try
                   {

                       JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response.toString());


                       JSONArray data=object.getJSONArray("results");

                       for( i=0;i<data.length();i++)
                       {
                           JSONObject json = data.getJSONObject(i);
                           final CurrentEntry c=new CurrentEntry();
                           userUrl=json.getString("list");
                           JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, userUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                   try {
                                       JSONObject temp=response.getJSONObject("user");

                                       String foodie_name=temp.getString("first_name");
                                           String lname=temp.getString("last_name");
                                       c.setName(name+"\t"+lname);
                                       progressDialog.dismiss();

                                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                   }
                                 //  adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                               }
                           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                               }
                           })

                           AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request,second_req);
                           c.setPeople(json.getString("no_people"));
                           String temp=json.getString("predicated_t");
                           c.setEstimate(temp+"min");
                         //  c.setNo(count);
                           TempUserStatusInfo info=new TempUserStatusInfo();
                           Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                           bundle.putParcelable("myList",c);
                           info.setArguments(bundle);
                           current.add(c);
                           adapt=new NewAdapter(current,getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                           recyclerView.setAdapter(adapt);

                        }


                }
                   catch (JSONException e)
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }

                }
```

This is code for receiving the ArrayList where I am setting `SwipeCards`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp_user_status_info, container, false);
        swipeCardsView=(SwipeCardsView)v.findViewById(R.id.swipeCard);
        infoAdapter=new CurrentInfoAdapter(info,getActivity());
        swipeCardsView.retainLastCard(false);
        swipeCardsView.enableSwipe(true);
        CurrentInfo currentInfo=new CurrentInfo();

        Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null){
            currentInfo=bundle.getParcelable("myList");
        }


        person_name=getArguments().getString("name");
        person_people=getArguments().getString("people");
        person_estimate=getArguments().getString("estimate");

        currentInfo.setName(person_name);
        currentInfo.setPeople(person_people);
        currentInfo.setEstimate(person_estimate);
        Log.i("name",person_name);
        Log.i("people",person_people);
        Log.i("estimate",person_estimate);
        info.add(currentInfo);
        swipeCardsView.setAdapter(infoAdapter);
        return v;
    }
```

The error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at biz.fyra.QueueApp.TempUserStatusInfo.onCreateView(TempUserStatusInfo.java:52)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2248)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1569)
```

Comment: Please stop using the [tag] markdown for class names. Instead, use the proper name - e.g., ArrayList - and surround it with backticks, ` - `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your are not set string values but your trying to receive that value. that why your getting null pointer exception .Pass string value also.

```
TempUserStatusInfo info=new TempUserStatusInfo();
                       Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                       bundle.putParcelable("myList",c) 
    bundle.putString("name",value);
    bundle.putString("people",value);
    bundle.putString("estimate",value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use correct arraylist to send parceable arraylist not the class object

```
putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", infoArrayList);
```

where custom object arraylist is

```
ArrayList<CurrentInfo> infoArrayList;
```

in Recieving `Fragment` class use this

```
ArrayList<CurrentInfo> infoArrayList = bundle.getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");
```

Comment: It is giving me error as Imcompatible Types

Comment: did u use this class CurrentEntry ?

Comment: Yes it s my Custom object for ArrayList

Comment: okay make it parceable and use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Serializable` for this

```
//for putting in bundle
bundle.putSerializable("key", class_value)

//for receieving
object = arguments.getSerializable("key") as className
```

Do not forget to extend the class with `serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use Gson to make json object and then make string of it send this string and on other side again make object from that json string using Gson.

Convert Java object to JSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Staff obj = new Staff();
String jsonInString = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Revert from json to object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Staff.class);
```

Add following dependency to your gradle file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

By doing this you dont have to serialize/deserialize and you can send it as string.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to pass arraylist one fragment to another

your first Fragment

```
ArrayList<ParcelableRow> parceArrayList = new ArrayList<ParcelableRow>();
Bundle bundle=new Bundle(); bundle.putParcelableArrayListExtra("yourArraylist",parceArrayList);
```

get Arraylist in other Fragment

```
ArrayList<ParcelableRow> result = data.getParcelableArrayList("yourArraylist");
```

Comment: I am getting error when i receive ArrayList Incompatible types.
Required:
ArrayList
<App.Model.CurrentInfo>
Found:
ArrayList
<App.Model.CurrentInfo & android.os.Parcelable>

Comment: how you receiving arraylist can you please  show the code?

Comment: ArrayList<CurrentInfo> current=getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("MyList");

Comment: did u implement Parcelable in your CurrentInfo class ?

Comment: No.Is there a case I need to implement Parcelable in both CurrentEntry and CurrentInfo ?

Comment: you need to implement Parcelable to get the arraylist in another fragement.try and let me know does it make any difference or not

Comment: Now  I am done with this.That error resolved. Now how to get and set the data in current fragment  ?

Comment: you got the list  now  read understand do it by your own.thank you

Comment: I got this error    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: we can only show you the path how do things rest of things you need to do it by your own try to debug the code and see where things going wrong.thank you